# Why am I getting an infinite loop with pg_search?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pg-search

When I point my browser at `http://localhost:3000/searches`, I get the following error:

`Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.`

Why? And how do I fix this?

Relevant code below...

**/config/routes.rb**:

```
resources :searches, :only => [:index]
```

**/app/controllers/searches_controller.rb**:

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController  
  respond_to :html
  filter_access_to :all
  def index
    @term = params[:term]
    @results = PgSearch.multisearch(@term) unless @term.blank?
    redirect_to searches_path
  end
end
```

**/app/views/searches/index.html.haml**:

```
.textbox
  = render "shared/notice"
  %h1 Advanced Search
  = simple_form_for @searches do |f|
    = f.input :term
    = f.button :submit
  - unless @results.blank?
    - @results.each do |result|
      %h3= result.searchable.header
      %p= result.searchable.body
```

**/config/authorization_rules.rb**:

```
authorization do
  role :admin do
    has_permission_on [...snip... :searches], :to => [:index, :show, :new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy, :print, :none, :audit]     
  end
end
```

**/app/models/reference.rb**:

```
class Reference < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail
  include PgSearch
  multisearchable :against => [:source_text, :citation]
  attr_accessible :reference_ids, :question_ids
  attr_accessible :url, :citation, :details, :veracity_id, :original, :source_text
  has_many :footnotes
  def header
    self.citation
  end
  def body
    self.details
  end
end
```

**/app/models/footnote.rb**:

```
class Footnote < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail
  include PgSearch
  multisearchable :against => [:details]
  attr_accessible :reference_id, :details, :page_range, :relevant
  belongs_to :reference
  def header
    [self.reference.citation, " ", self.page_range].join
  end  
  def body
    self.details
  end
end
```

**/db/migrate/20130326110126_create_pg_search_documents.rb**:

```
class CreatePgSearchDocuments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    say_with_time("Creating table for pg_search multisearch") do
      create_table :pg_search_documents do |t|
        t.text :content
        t.belongs_to :searchable, :polymorphic => true
        t.timestamps
      end
    end
  end
  def self.down
    say_with_time("Dropping table for pg_search multisearch") do
      drop_table :pg_search_documents
    end
  end
end
```

**/db/migrate/20130326110723_rebuild_search_indexes.rb**:

```
class RebuildSearchIndexes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    PgSearch::Multisearch.rebuild(Reference)
    PgSearch::Multisearch.rebuild(Footnote)
  end
  def down
    PgSearch::Reference.delete_all
    PgSearch::Footnote.delete_all
  end
end
```

Comment: Looks like a cyclic redirect. Doesn't `redirect_to searches_path` just send the request back into the same action?

Comment: I thought it sent me back to /app/views/searches.html.haml. I was planning to use this page to both show search results and to collect search terms. But do I have to somehow break the process into two actions?

Comment: Try just taking the `redirect_to` line out. That way Rails will render `app/views/searches/index.html.haml` by default. Then posting to the form should request `index` again and produce what you want.

Comment: Thanks. That killed the loop. Now trying to work out the correct syntax for the `= simple_form_for @search do |f|` line. (As @search does not exist.)

Comment: Great. I'll post it as an answer. If you need help with the `@search` bit, I'd suggest a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a cyclic redirect; `redirect_to searches_path` just sends the request back into the same action.

Try just taking the `redirect_to` line out. That way Rails will render `app/views/searches/index.html.haml` by default. Then posting to the form should request `index` again and produce what you want.

Comment: That worked. Then updated form to:
  = form_tag searches_path, :method => :get do
    = text_field_tag "term", "Search term"
    = submit_tag "Search"